# Accessing Textbox selected value in c#

Tags: c#

I have multi-lines textbox in c# window-base application. If user click on textbox I want to get the value of selected line. Kindly guide me so that I can make it possible.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something along the lines of:

```
// Get selected character.
int charIndex = textbox.SelectionStart;

// Get line index from selected character.
int lineIndex = textbox.GetLineFromCharIndex(charIndex);

// Get line.
string line = textbox.Lines[lineIndex];
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm hoping that you mean a listbox?

`listBox.SelectedItem gives a ListItem` and then you can get the Text or Value from there

Answer (score 1):

If its a multi-line enabled textbox you can use the `Lines` property.

Answer (score 1):

Very briefly:

```
int sel = this.textBox1.SelectionStart;
string text = this.textBox1.Text;
int selstart = 0;
int selend = 0;
int i = 0;
for (i = sel; i > 0; i--)
    if (text[i] == '\n')
        break;
selstart = i;
for (i = sel; i < text.Length; i++)
    if (text[i] == '\n')
        break;
selend = i;
string line = text.Substring(selstart, selend - selstart);
```

'line' is the line you pointed.

EDITED: Fara posted better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the KeyUp event, like:
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
MyString = TextBox1.SelectedText
End Sub